# Accidentally set C: as active partition: Windows won't boot - live USB system won't boot - suddenly CPU overtemperature error?

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning, temperature, boot-partition

I just accidentally set the system partition `C:\` as active in Windows 7's disk management, trying to get this *absolutely useless* Windows backup & restore program to work. Now I can no longer boot: `Bootmgr is missing. Press Ctrl + Alt + Delete to restart.` How can I set the 100 MB boot partition in front of it back to active?

Using Linux Mint's disk image writer, I already created a bootable Windows 10 USB flash drive, but the system just won't recognize it - what's the matter? I played around with the BIOS settings (boot order, USB support, some CMS/UEFI/legacy boot and Secure Boot settings etc.), but it just won't start from the USB flash drive.

What's even more strange: I'm getting a `CPU Overtemperature Error! Press F1 to Run SETUP` *at every single reboot* and the CPU temperature is hitting **84-86 °C** even though I did not (consciously) change *any* setting related to the CPU. What have I done? How can setting the wrong partition as active have such unforeseen consequences? The BIOS offers advanced controls for CPU overclocking etc. - is it possible that BIOS saves some of these settings in the boot partition and now it's unable to load them?

Please help...I need to get this fixed **fast**. It's a workplace PC required for measurements and I was just in the process of creating the first system disk image when this mess happened (got no recovery options). The PC has no CD/DVD drive, so I'm stuck with using USB flash drives to get this solved.

PS.: I will post detailed information on the ASUS BIOS shortly.

Comment: Things you can try : re-creating windows 7 bootable USB (hope you have the iso) from linux(mint in your case)(instructions - https://www.ghacks.net/2018/05/25/windows-bootable-usb-woeusb/amp/) or just partition drive and install linux mint (can remove afterwards if not needed) and use linux mint grub to boot windows or use boot repair (it comes pre-installed in newer linux mint live-cd to repair and restore windows bootloader or try setting boot flag from linux (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/343429/314322)

Comment: Okay, I'll try it first with a live Linux Mint USB flash drive (hopefully it will boot) and try to set the boot flag with `fdisk`

Comment: For CPU Overtemperature Error - maybe you need to replace the thermal paste or make sure the fan attached to your cpu cooler is fully plugged in and working properly ; and if you think you have messed up the bios setting then there is an option in bios something like load optimised defaults and load failsafe defaults , choose any one of them

Comment: Thanks, I saw the option for default settings, but didn't want to touch the BIOS yet, as I didn't set up the system (don't want to break anything). The BIOS options are quite extensive, I will upload screenshots shortly... Regarding the CPU overtemperature issue, I'm positive this is directly related to the boot problems as there has never been anything temperature-related in the past. Also, the PC is not incredibly old and the i7 has a **huge** heatsink-cooler + fan on it

Comment: is it possible that BIOS saves some of these settings in the boot partition and now it's unable to load them? - No

Comment: Ahhh...the live Linux Mint flash drive immediately worked (Linux rocks)! Reset the boot flag using `fdisk` to the boot volume and everything is back to normal. (*phew...*) Many thanks for the quick help!!! If you want, you could post an answer... By the way, **no idea** what was going on with the CPU. The temperature spiked up to 85 °C within 2-3 minutes after starting the PC and entering BIOS. Now, back in Windows 7, `CPUID HWMonitor` shows all cores at nominal temp...

Comment: By the way, is there a way to remove the "active"/boot flag from the root volume (C:\) from within Windows' disk management utility (*Right Click on Computer > Manage > Storage > Disk Management*)? The boot volume now has the flags *System/Active/Primary Partition* and C: has *Boot, Page File, Active, Crash Dump, Primary Partition* - so still set to active and there is no obvious way to reverse it (setting it is done by *Right Click on volume > Mark partition as active*)

Comment: ...okay, this can be done in Windows using `diskpart` from `cmd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you can try : re-creating windows 7 bootable USB (hope you have the iso) from linux(mint in your case)(instructions - https://www.ghacks.net/2018/05/25/windows-bootable-usb-woeusb/amp/) or just partition drive and install linux mint (can remove afterwards if not needed) and use linux mint grub to boot windows or use boot repair (it comes pre-installed in newer linux mint live-cd to repair and restore windows bootloader or try setting boot flag from linux (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/343429/314322)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding a bit on Madhubala's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1576544/941977), this is the step-by-step solution that worked for me:

- 1.) Create a live (= bootable) Linux flash drive from a downloaded ISO. This is super simple, from Linux using `gnome-disks` (menu > *Restore Disk Image* > follow instructions) or from Windows using e.g. [Rufus](https://rufus.ie). For some reason, creating a live *Windows* flash drive *never* works for me, so I stick with Linux.
- 2.) Launch Linux from the flash drive, open a terminal, and reset the boot flag to the correct partition using `fdisk` as described in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/343497/311155) answer.
- 3.) Now, Windows should boot normally! The accidental "active" (boot) flag can be removed using `diskpart` from the Windows command line as described in [this](https://serverfault.com/a/276848) answer.